# trouble in hadoop 2.2.0 instalation in ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: hadoop

while installing hadoop 2.2.0 i came up with this error. please help me out in solving this.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.11.0-15-generic x86_64)
```

- Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  ```
  Last login: Mon May 19 12:02:59 2014 from localhost
  vandana@Vandana:~$ start-all.sh
  This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
  14/05/20 17:49:37 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
  Starting namenodes on [localhost]
  localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/hadoop/logs': Permission denied
  localhost: chown: cannot access `/usr/local/hadoop/logs': No such file or directory
  localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-vandana-namenode-Vandana.out
  localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 151: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-vandana-namenode-Vandana.out: No such file or directory
  localhost: head: cannot open `/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-vandana-namenode-Vandana.out' for reading: No such file or directory
  localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 166: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-vandana-namenode-Vandana.out: No such file or directory
  localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 167: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-vandana-namenode-Vandana.out: No such file or directory
  localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/hadoop/logs': Permission denied
  localhost: chown: cannot access `/usr/local/hadoop/logs': No such file or directory
  localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-vandana-datanode-Vandana.out
  localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 151: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-vandana-datanode-Vandana.out: No such file or directory
  localhost: head: cannot open `/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-vandana-datanode-Vandana.out' for reading: No such file or directory
  localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 166: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-vandana-datanode-Vandana.out: No such file or directory
  localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 167: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-vandana-datanode-Vandana.out: No such file or directory
  Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
  0.0.0.0: mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/hadoop/logs': Permission denied
  0.0.0.0: chown: cannot access `/usr/local/hadoop/logs': No such file or directory
  0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-vandana-secondarynamenode-Vandana.out
  0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 151: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-vandana-secondarynamenode-Vandana.out: No such file or directory
  0.0.0.0: head: cannot open `/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-vandana-secondarynamenode-Vandana.out' for reading: No such file or directory
  0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 166: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-vandana-secondarynamenode-Vandana.out: No such file or directory
  0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 167: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-vandana-secondarynamenode-Vandana.out: No such file or directory
  14/05/20 17:50:02 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
  starting yarn daemons
  mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/hadoop/logs': Permission denied
  chown: cannot access `/usr/local/hadoop/logs': No such file or directory
  starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-vandana-resourcemanager-Vandana.out
  /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 124: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-vandana-resourcemanager-Vandana.out: No such file or directory
  head: cannot open `/usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-vandana-resourcemanager-Vandana.out' for reading: No such file or directory
  /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 129: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-vandana-resourcemanager-Vandana.out: No such file or directory
  /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 130: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-vandana-resourcemanager-Vandana.out: No such file or directory
  localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/hadoop/logs': Permission denied
  localhost: chown: cannot access `/usr/local/hadoop/logs': No such file or directory
  localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-vandana-nodemanager-Vandana.out
  localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 124:                            /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-vandana-nodemanager-Vandana.out: No such file or directory
  localhost: head: cannot open `/usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-vandana-nodemanager-Vandana.out' for reading: No such file or directory
  localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 129: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-vandana-nodemanager-Vandana.out: No such file or directory
  localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 130: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-vandana-nodemanager-Vandana.out: No such file or directory
  ```

Comment: Try to run the script in `sudo` mode. That will already clean all the permission errors from the output. And update your question but please consider formatting the error log so i can be user readable

Answer (score 2):

start-dfs.sh and start-mapred.sh instead of start-all.sh
And there seems to be aerror in your configuration files  hdfs-site.xml,core-site.xml,mapred-site.xml
check This for step by step installation:[Hadoop Installation](http://nitrek.blogspot.in/2015/03/hadoop-installation-commands.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have not permission to create logs file.
Configure hdfs-site.xml,core-site.xml,mapred-site.xml properly and make sure you have permission to format namenode

Answer (score -1):

I think it might be caused because you don't have the Hadoop natives jar files in the PATH. To add it you should run:

```
export PATH=$PATH;$HADOOP_INSTALL
```

Comment: 'Permission denied'. Not about native libs.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I only saw the "No such file...". The Hadoop user  (if you use it) or your user (vandana) must have write permissions on to the hadoop folder and subfolders. Check from /usr/local using ls -l that the "hadoop" folder has the correct permissions. You should never use the "sudo" in Hadoop because it will lead to many permissions problems, in fact, it is never neccesary